# Exploring date and address variables

Tags: date, regression, gis, logistic-regression

I have a dataset that contains date variables, quantitative and qualitative predictor variables,  and a binary dependent variable. The goal of my analysis is find the percent of success in `CORRECT` and to learn more about the relationship between `CORRECT` with the independent variables.

There are people we can call trackers that live throughout the US. Each one has the job of keeping track of the addresses for the participants of our program in their location. The problem is that some of these trackers are not regularly updating the address for the group of participants that they are responsible for. Some of the addresses in their database can be outdated or incorrect some other way. I’m looking to explore more into these correct/incorrect addresses and their relationship between the other variables. Below are some of the variables that I have in my dataset:

- `CORRECT`: a binary variable to indicate whether or not  the RECORDER entered the correct address
- `RECORDER_ADDRESS`: the address that the RECORDER put into their database for the participant
- `ACTUAL_ADDRESS`:  the address where the participant is actually  located
- `ZIP_CODE`:  the zip code for the participant
- `PARTICIPANT_ID`: The unique ID for the participant
- `CREATED_DATE`: date when the initial address for the participant was recorded
- `MODIFIED_DATE`: dates when any variable was modified
- `PARTICIPANT_START_DATE`: the start date for the participant on the job
- `PARTICIPANT_END_DATE`: the date when this participants duty will end
- `RECORDER`: name of the recorder that is in charge of tracking this entry
- `TRAINING`: the type of training that the participant received

I’ve figured out the accuracy of the `RECORDER`s. I found they were correct about 56% of the time. Now I’m trying to look more for into these incorrect and correct addresses. I’ve tried logistic regression to predict `CORRECT` but none of the predictor variables were significant. I made a stacked bar-plot using  the `CORRECT` variable and `STATE` along with `CORRECT` and `RECORDER`.  Now I’m resorting to using the 4 date variables along with the `ZIP_CODE`, `RECORDER_ADDRESS`, and `ACTUAL_ADDRESS` to learn about the success and failure of the `RECORDERS`. Are there some visualization ideas or analysis that  can use the date variables and/or  address variables  to gain insight about the correct/incorrect recordings?

An idea that can be used is to create another variable that’s the difference in time between `CREATED_DATE` and `MODIFIED_DATE`. Another difference for `PARTICIPANT_START_DATE` and `MODIFIED_DATE`.

Comment: You lost my attention somwhere at the second paragraph. Your question needs a little visualization and code I guess to follow you through what you typed and problem statement.

Comment: Have a look at formatting as well.

Comment: do those dates store time of day? if so, perhaps you could consider change in accuracy over time of day (e.g fatigue/boredom) i.e. human factors. Also is accuracy just binary? can't an address be "almost correct"? To go further with your question I believe you need to provide sample data at the very least.

Comment: *Are there some visualization ideas or analysis that can use the date variables and/or address variables to gain insight about the correct/incorrect recordings?* – this is a too broad question, I'd say. Please try to shrink your text and ask about something more specific